# Are there any fantasy campaign setting/modules analogous to the Silk Road?

Tags: campaign-settings

I am winding up my current campaign and looking to start a new one. The idea is to run a fantasy campaign where there is a clash of different cultures in a trade-city and was looking for a fantasy campaign/module/adventure path set in something like the Silk Road.

I've already got the [book](http://e23.sjgames.com/item.html?id=XRP1005) "A Magical Society: Silk Road" but was wondering if there's anything I have missed.

Comment: A history book you should read is [Foreign Devils on the Silk Road: The Search for the Lost Treasures of Central Asia by Peter Hopkirk](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Foreign-Devils-Silk-Road-Treasures/dp/0719564484/ref=la_B000APBS8I_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1365415283&sr=1-2).  The introduction chapter reads like a (bad) D&D module with lost cities, forgotten for a thousand years, filled with treasures and guarded by demons.

Comment: Don't almost all settings have "the huge intercultural trade city" at some point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Dark Sun](http://www.athas.org/) is a setting that is a perfect fit for such a fantasy milieu. The City of Tyr is a trade city with a clash of cultures, especially after it gaining its new-found freedom from the rule of its sorcerer king. The [Dune Trader](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dune_Trader) accessory (for AD&D 2nd) gives the rules for merchants and trading. The adventures are epic but still provide enough opportunities and motivation for trading characters (I myself played through the adventure path with a dune trader character, and it was much fun.)

Another good setting is [Earthdawn](http://earthdawn.fasagames.com/). Here, the cities of Bartertown and Vivaine are good choices  to center a trading campaign upon. I don't remember Earthdawn having specific rules for trading, but quite a few character archetypes and skills support the idea.